# Grails 2.4 spring-security-facebook:0.15.2-CORE2 redirect error - Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security, upgrade, spring-social-facebook

I just upgraded one project of mine from grails 2.3.5 to 2.4.2 and ajust
all the plugins (as shown below inside my buildConfig) to work correctly.

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":aws:1.6.7.5"
    compile ":console:1.3"
    compile ":mongodb:3.0.1"
    compile ":rest:0.8"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    // runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.7" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"

    runtime ":pretty-time:0.3"
    runtime ":mail:1.0.6"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-facebook:0.15.2-CORE2"
    compile ":grails-melody:1.49.0"
}
```

The project runs okay but facebook plugin not yet.
I'm using FacebookAuthRedirectFilter (the default). But when I click the 
connect button at the view, the request is intercepted by the FacebookAuthRedirectFilter 
as expected, enters the if statement, the facebookAuthUtils prepares the url perfectly
but after that the view should redirect to facebook generated url.

```
if (uri.equals(redirectFromUrl)) {    
    response.sendRedirect(facebookAuthUtils.prepareRedirectUrl(getAbsoluteRedirectUrl(), facebookAuthUtils.requiredPermissions))
        return false
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
2014-07-14 22:14:39,838 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR [/].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception
Message: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
Line | Method
->>   91 | sendError in net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    203 | doFilter  in net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter
|    181 | doFilter  in     ''
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker 
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: it's https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-facebook/issues/64 will fix soon

Comment: please try version 0.15.3-CORE2